# Python - mongoDB query

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to create endpoint that will accept search criteria in body and returns documents from mongoDB that are meeting requirements. I did it using just Dict as input type but I want to put some validation on it by creating a serach mode.

let's assume that it looks like this:

```
class SearchUser(BaseModel):
    login: Optional[str] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
    device: Optional[SearchDevice] = None

class SearchDevice(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[str] = None
    description: Optional[str] = None
```

almost everything works fine with that solution but to search based on user device I need to provide full model like (if not it's not returning required value):

```
    "device": 
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "type",
        "description": "desc"
      }
```

and I want to be able to use it like:

```
 "device": 
      {
        "name": "name"
      }
```

Could someone advise me how to achieve that?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Perhaps if you show what a document looks like, your query, the response, and your desired response, your question would be clearer.